# How to plot maximum/minimum value plot for selected item's category

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Table 1:

| Date | Item | Sales Amont |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/01/2021 | Apple | 300 |
| 10/02/2022 | Orange | 700 |
| 20/03/2022 | Carrot | 300 |
| 21/03/2022 | Onion | 800 |

Table 2:

| Date | Item | Category | Sales Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/01/2021 | Apple | Fruits | 300 |
| 20/02/2022 | Carrot | Vegetable | 800 |
| 10/02/2022 | Orange | Fruits | 700 |
| 21/03/2022 | Onion | Vegetable | 200 |

Relationship: Table1[Item] and Table2[Item] are connect using Many to many relationship.

Im trying to plot three lines of graph for table 1.

Line 1- Represents the maximum sale amount based on its category(category value retrieved from selected value of item displayed in slicer)

Line 2 – Represents the sale amount of selected item over the date.

Line 3 -- Represents the minimum sale amount based on its category(category value retrieved from selected value of item displayed in slicer)

My Problem is

Unable to plot the maximum/minimum sale amount line based on the slicer item category.

When you change the item in the slicer, the maximum/minimum line chart must be updated based on the selected item category, but in this case, the lines change based on the selected item value rather than the max/min value.

My Question is:

How to plot the maximum/minimum value chart only based selected item’s category.

Example :

If I choose the apple in the slicer, the maximum/minimum plot will show the maximum and minimum value of the fruits category.

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of `Table2`? Is it just to match items with a category and all other data are to be taken from `Table1` ?

Comment: Table 2 has different dates and different sale amounts, the reason for table 2 here is I'm just referring category column in table 1 @JérémieL

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I've given it a try.

First, I've modified the model to be closer to a typical PowerBI model. It makes everything much easier. Namely:

- I've converted `Table2` into a `Category` table.
- I've created a `Calendar` table.

The new `Category` table looks like that:

| Item | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Fruits |
| Carrot | Vegetable |
| Orange | Fruits |
| Onion | Vegetable |

The calendar table is just a table expression:

```
Calendar = CALENDAR(DATE(2022, 01, 01), DATE(2022, 03, 31))
```

I end up with a model looking like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Then, regarding your calculations:

> Line 1- Represents the maximum sale amount based on its category(category value retrieved from selected value of item displayed in slicer)

```
Cat_MaxSalesAmount = 
MAXX(
    Sales,
    Sales[Sales Amont]
)
```

> Line 2 – Represents the sale amount of selected item over the date.

```
Sales_AllCategories = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sales[Sales Amont]),
    ALL(Category[Category])
)
```

> Line 3 -- Represents the minimum sale amount based on its category(category value retrieved from selected value of item displayed in slicer)

```
Cat_MinSalesAmount = 
MINX(
    Sales,
    Sales[Sales Amont]
)
```

I've tried it in table visualisation and the different calculations are modified by the filters.

[image: Table]

Comment: Jeremie L Thanks for reply,

 Actually, I need a combo box (slicer) with an item column instead of a category column, so that when I select an item, the corresponding category values will be plotted in max/min lines.